# Can you prune a date locator in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

When setting the major locator as a DayLocator with Matplotlib, the plot shows a day before and after my date range.  Is there a way to prune the range like you can with the MaxNLocator?
Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(pd.Series(index=pd.date_range('2019-1-1','2019-1-31',freq='D'),data=range(31)))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%#d'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get an extra tick is that there is a 5% margin on each side of the line, such that the next day is actually part of the axis range. 
You can reduce the margin via `ax.margins(...)`. In this case e.g.

```
ax.margins(x=1/31)
```